# How to associate DOM attributes to each item in Mongo Collection

Tags: meteor

How can I give some HTML attributes to each item in a Mongo Collection in Meteor? My use case is:

- I have a collection of documents (pdfs)
- I want to display a thumb for each of them
- On the template, each document is an article.document which is absolutely positioned
- I want to assign a Math.random() value for the "top" and "left" for each article.document

My code: http://meteorpad.com/pad/bq6Ph5CQXMMejFQiF/DocumentList

document-list.html:

```
<template name="documentList">
    {{#each documents}}
      <article class="document {{#if active}}active{{/if}}">
        <header class="document-header">
          <div class="document-avatar btn-floating lighten-3"></div>
        </header>
      </article>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

document-list.js:

```
Template.documentList.helpers({
  documents: function() {
    return Documents.find({});
  }
});
```

My doubt is: where should I do the calculation for the random values of the article.document elements and when should I assign the values to the DOM nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should separate out the document template:

```
<template name="documentList">
    {{#each documents}}
        {{> document}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="document">
  <article class="document {{#if active}}active{{/if}}">
    <header class="document-header">
      <div class="document-avatar btn-floating lighten-3"></div>
    </header>
  </article>
</template>
```

Now you can create a rendered function that will be called for each document that's rendered into the DOM:

```
Template.document.rendered = function() {

  var $article = $(this.find('article'));

  // Add the position attributes etc. using JQuery

  $article.css({ 
    position: "absolute",
    top: 10, left: 10
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @tarmes, just so I can fully understand, the inner template inherits the data context, so I should keep my documentList.helpers.documents as is?

Comment: The data context will be inherited. Note though that documentList.helpers.documents is used by the 'documents' template (not the inner one) in any case.